# Angular $HTTP posting- dynamic URL and defining post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am trying to post a simple binary value (using $http) to a URL which si defined by a value in my HTML.

I have successfully got the "card.id" being passed through (can see it in console log)

```
                <td-card ng-repeat="card in cards"
                         on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)"
                         on-swipe="cardSwiped($index)"
                         on-swipe-right="$parent.cardSwiped(card.id)"
                         on-swipe-left="$parent.cardSwiped(card.id)" >
```

The data I want to post needs to be to a URL which has the card.id in it.

How to I tell it what to post and how to trigger?

```
.controller('CardsCtrl', ['$scope', 'TDCardDelegate', 'cardsApi', '$http',
    function($scope, TDCardDelegate, cardsApi, $http) {
       console.log('CARDS CTRL');
        $scope.cards = [];

        $scope.onSwipeRight=function(product_id){console.log(product_id)}
        //Post for swipe right {'like':1, 'uid':21}

        $scope.onSwipeLeft=function(product_id){console.log(product_id)}
        //Post for swipe left {'like':0, 'uid':21}

             for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                 cardsApi.getApiData()
                     .then(function (result) {
                         $scope.cards.unshift(result.data);
                         $scope.product_id = result.data.product_id;
                     })
                     .catch(function (err) {
                         $log.error(err);
                     });
             }

             $scope.$watchCollection('cards', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                 if(newVal < oldVal) {
                     cardsApi.getApiData()
                         .then(function (result) {
                             $scope.cards.unshift(result.data);
                         })
                         .catch(function (err) {
                             console.log(err);
                         });
                 }
             });

             $scope.cardSwiped = function(card) {
         console.log('here');
         console.log(card);
       };
         //Removes card from top of stack
         $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
             $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
         };

         $scope.addCard = function() {
             var newCard = $scope.cards[$scope.cards.length];
             //newCard.id = Math.random();
             $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
         };

        $scope.postRecordLikes = function(product_id){
            console.log(product_id)
            $http.post('http://test.com/analytic/' + product_id)
                .then(function successCallback(product_id) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });
        };
    }
])
```

Comment: where are you calling `postRecordLikes` ?

Comment: No where else. This may have been a mistake

Answer (score 1):

`postRecordLikes` is being defined but never used. You can call it in your html by different ways. If you want to call it when you click it for example, just use `ng-click`.

By the way, calling $http inside your controller is not a good practice, have a look at this post: https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/

**EDIT**

I have forked your plunkr. Take a look at it: http://plnkr.co/edit/uvooKeCtFagAnFjVYnhS?p=preview

You should call `postRecordLikes` when your event is fired. Modify it as you want.

Comment: Please show me how this would be done in my example- I have followed the docs and it still isn't clear.

Comment: OK, but first explain a little bit better what you need. When the http POST should be triggered? When someone clicks on certain card?

Comment: On every card, a post should trigger. For swipe right of a card- it should post {'like':1, 'uid':21} to 'http://test.com/analytic/1234 (1234=product_id, taken from the HTML). For left, the same except {'like':0, 'uid':21}.

Comment: but do you already have a way of managing that event? so you call postRecordLikes when that event fires?

Comment: No- I do not belive I do. I put this in a plunkr to make easier- http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScnGyy2eAmGwcJ7XZ2Z?p=preview

Comment: Ok now I am understanding what you want. You should send that post when the user clicks on the yes button?

Comment: Almost there- I still dont see the part where the data "posts" the json result. I am not sure how to make this

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking, please be a little bit clearer

Comment: I do not see that the $http post is being done (ie the pre-defined Json data I mentioned earlier)- {'like':1, 'uid':21} to 'test.com/analytic/1234 (1234=product_id, taken from the HTML), for left {'like':0, 'uid':21}

Comment: Your $http.post is being used in a wrong way. Please, verify that the API is correctly implemented and that you are calling it in a good way

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the plunkr to use the correct address (http://plnkr.co/edit/tPiPszvlOgLSkLkgoK5k?p=preview). I still do not see how the specific json is being sent for either left or right swipe. Can you give an example of where this occurs?

Comment: The message given is 400 - bad request. Maybe you should include an object to the Post so that the request is valid. Verify again that your api has to be used in that way and consider sending an object. Read again https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http